# units conversion while coding for physics in android

Tags: android, game-physics

I am trying to draw a projectile motion for my app depending on initial angle set by user.As part of my assumptions, I have assumed initial velocity to be 400 pixels/second.But as we know that the accleration due to gravity is in m/s2 , so how do I perform units conversion or do I need to change the assumptions about my unit for velocity.

please suggest me the units for distance also.My assumption is pixels.is this good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all your calculations in physical units (i.e. meters, seconds) and afterwards scale it to your device screen using this factor. Just incorporate the factor `meter/pixel` into your equations and everything will fit together.